# How to render <br> tags actually as line breaks in Yii2 mpdf

Tags: html, yii2, mpdf

I have this in one of my models:

```
public function getDispname() {
    return $this->step . '<br>' . $this->pm->dispname;
}
```

In the View (_pdf.php) I'm calling it inside of a Gridview.
When I'm generating a pdf about this in the controller:

```
$pdf = \Yii::$app->pdf;
$pdf->content = $this->render('_pdf', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
$pdf->render();
```

I'm getting this result:

```
7. - sometext<br>sometext
```

Obviously I would like to have an actual line break there instead of a `<br>` tag:

```
7. - sometext
sometext
```

Can you please tell me how can I make mpdf to render `<br>` tags as line breaks?

Comment: Does the `<br>` work outside of the Gridview? I have just run your code (outside of a Gridview) without any problem.

Comment: What is you code for GridView? You can try to add `'format' => 'raw',` to your column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text for columns in GridView are automatically encoded.

So to render html you need to format this column as raw text.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ...
        // a column with html inside as raw text
        [
            'attribute' => 'content',
            'format' => 'raw', // this will enable html output
        ],
        ...
    ],
]); ?>
```